# Efficiant way to manipulate very large json files?

Tags: json, extract

i was searching the net for way to extract data from very large json files
some stack that let me import the json file , and execute xpath/sql like scripts on the data
to extract data from it .
can you please recommend me on such development stack ?
i do want to avoid loading the json in c++/java and program this .
MongoDB ?

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB is great for this kind of task. You can import the data to a MongoDB database using the `mongoimport` utility

```
mongoimport --db DB_NAME --collection COLLECTION_NAME --file YOUR_JSON_FILE
```

You can then explore the data using `mongo` client.

```
$ mongo
> use DB_NAME
> db.COLLECTION_NAME.find()
```

You may need to index some fields for faster lookup

```
> db.COLLECTION_NAME.ensureIndex({FIELD_NAME:1})
```

The mongodb [manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/contents/) is really helpful for getting started.

Comment: i did it got error's :
 exception:BSON representation of supplied JSON is too large: Failure parsing JSON string near: "name": "T

 Assertion: 10340:Failure parsing JSON string near: "id": "541

Comment: hmm, can you give some sample lines in your json file?

Comment: here is new question :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109474/mongodb-mongoimport-too-large-failure-parsing-errors