# Mongodb Mongoimport too large: Failure parsing errors

Tags: json, mongodb, import

I am trying to import into MongoDB 70 mb json file that is valid. But, I am getting this error over and over in a loop:

```
 01 11:42:20 exception:BSON representation of supplied JSON is too large: Failure parsing JSON string near: "name": "L
 01 11:42:20
 01 11:42:20 Assertion: 10340:Failure parsing JSON string near: "link": "h
 01 11:42:20 mongoimport.exe    ???
 01 11:42:20 mongoimport.exe    ???
 01 11:42:20 mongoimport.exe    ???
 01 11:42:20 mongoimport.exe    ???
 01 11:42:20 mongoimport.exe    ???
 01 11:42:20 mongoimport.exe    ???
 01 11:42:20 mongoimport.exe    ???
 01 11:42:20 kernel32.dll       BaseThreadInitThunk+0x12
 01 11:42:20 ntdll.dll          RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0xef
 01 11:42:20 exception:BSON representation of supplied JSON is too large: Failure parsing JSON string near: "link": "h
 01 11:42:20
 01 11:42:20 Assertion: 10340:Failure parsing JSON string near: }
 01 11:42:20 mongoimport.exe    ???
 01 11:42:20 mongoimport.exe    ???
 01 11:42:20 mongoimport.exe    ???
 01 11:42:20 mongoimport.exe    ???
 01 11:42:20 mongoimport.exe    ???
 01 11:42:20 mongoimport.exe    ???
 01 11:42:20 mongoimport.exe    ???
 01 11:42:20 kernel32.dll       BaseThreadInitThunk+0x12
 01 11:42:20 ntdll.dll          RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0xef
 01 11:42:20 exception:BSON representation of supplied JSON is too large: Failure parsing JSON string near: }
 01 11:42:20
 01 11:42:20 Assertion: 10340:Failure parsing JSON string near: ],
 01 11:42:20 mongoimport.exe    ???
 01 11:42:20 mongoimport.exe    ???
 01 11:42:20 mongoimport.exe    ???
 01 11:42:20 mongoimport.exe    ???
 01 11:42:20 mongoimport.exe    ???
 01 11:42:20 mongoimport.exe    ???
 01 11:42:20 mongoimport.exe    ???
 01 11:42:20 kernel32.dll       BaseThreadInitThunk+0x12
 01 11:42:20 ntdll.dll          RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0xef
 01 11:42:20 exception:BSON representation of supplied JSON is too large: Failure parsing JSON string near: ],
```

My JSON ( only small example from it ) consist many many structures like this one :

```
[ 
{
   "data": [
         "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
         "from": {
            "name": "yyyyyyyyyyy",
            "id": "1111111111111"
         },
         "to": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "version": 1,
                  "name": "1111111111111",
                  "id": "1111111111111"
               }
            ]
         },
         "picture": "fffffffffffffffffffffff.jpg",
         "link": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqqqqqqqqqqqq",
         "source": "http://www.youtube.com/v/qqqqqqqqqqqqq?version=3&autohide=1&autoplay=1",
         "name": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
         "description": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...",
         "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/xxx/r/dddd",
         "actions": [
            {
               "name": "Comment",
               "link": "http://www.example.com/1111111111111/posts/1111111111111"
            },
            {
               "name": "Like",
               "link": "http://www.example.com/1111111111111/posts/1111111111111"
            }
         ],
         "privacy": {
            "value": ""
         },
         "type": "video",
         "created_time": 1356953890,
         "updated_time": 1356953890,
         "likes": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "name": "jjj ",
                  "id": "59xxx67"
               },
               {
                  "name": "xxxxx",
                  "id": "79xxx27"
               }
            ],
            "count": 2
         },
         "comments": {
            "count": 0
         }
      },

....
....
....
}
]
```

this is the general patern of the json ":

```
[
{
   "data": [
      {

      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "previous": "link",
      "next": "link"
   }
},
   "data": [
      {
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "previous": "link",
      "next": "link"
   }
},
"data": [
      {
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "previous": "link",
      "next": "link"
   }
}
]
```

Answer (score 78):

Instead of using:

```
mongoimport -d DATABASE_NAME -c COLLECTION_NAME --file YOUR_JSON_FILE
```

use the following command:

```
mongoimport -d DATABASE_NAME -c COLLECTION_NAME --file YOUR_JSON_FILE --jsonArray
```

Comment: me too! the --jsonArray parameter made all the difference. Shame it can't detect just a json array.

Comment: Such a simple annoying problem.  I was about to write a script to insert one document at a time.  You saved me from that.  Thanks for the quick fix.

Answer (score 14):

In my case my file was actually not too large, so the error message was misleading.  I had to either put each document in a single line or use `--jsonArray`.

So either change the file like:

```
{ "_id" : "xxxxxxxx", "foo" : "yyy", "bar" : "zzz" }
```

or change the import command to

```
mongoimport -d [db_name] -c [col_name] --file [file_with_multi_lined_docs] --jsonArray
```

if my file stays in the multiple-lines-per-document format

```
{
    "_id" : "xxxxxxxx", 
    "foo" : "yyy", 
    "bar" : "zzz" 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Is your json file only contains a list of records in the `data` field? In that case, you need to re-format your json file as a list of records like the following:

```
     {
     "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
     "from": {
        "name": "yyyyyyyyyyy",
        "id": "1111111111111"
     },
     "to": {
        "data": [
           {
              "version": 1,
              "name": "1111111111111",
              "id": "1111111111111"
           }
        ]
     },
     ......
     }
     {
     "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
     "from": {
        "name": "yyyyyyyyyyy",
        "id": "1111111111111"
     },
     "to": {
        "data": [
           {
              "version": 1,
              "name": "1111111111111",
              "id": "1111111111111"
           }
        ]
     },
     ......
     }
```

Just edit the a few leading/ending lines should be enough if your json file is well formatted.

**EDIT**: You may need the `--jsonArray` option to import from a valid json file. try

```
mongoimport --db DATABASE_NAME --collection COLLECTION_NAME --file YOUR_JSON_FILE --jsonArray
```

Comment: in this case, you may use the `--jsonArray` option. try `mongoimport --db DATABASE_NAME --collection COLLECTION_NAME --file YOUR_JSON_FILE --jsonArray`.

Comment: hi i got somethihg but still error:
mongoimport  --collection ping_collaction --file  group_result31.12.2012.json --jsonArray
Tue Jan 01 16:04:53 exception:JSONArray file too large
Tue Jan 01 16:04:53 warning: log line attempted (16384k) over max size(10k), printing beginning and end ...
... some json ...
Tue Jan 01 16:04:53 imported 0 objects
Tue Jan 01 16:04:53 ERROR: encountered 1 error

Comment: the warning is no problem, just telling your it shortened the line to keep log file smaller. To the first error, as @WPCoder suggests in another answer, is there any record that are larger than 16MB?

Comment: ok sorry for the begginer questions , but what does mongoDB see as record? the total file is 80 mega

Comment: yes its bigger then 16 , is there something to do ?
mybe other tool ? or other DB that support json

Comment: --jsonArray that was the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of mongo, I had the problem that I exported json from mongo 2.6.1 and tried to import on a mongo ~2.4, after installing a higher version it worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when faced with this error, I found that the problem was from copying and pasting the data from my local machine (in vim) to my remote server (also vim). When I `scp`'d it across instead it miraculously worked, so no idea what was being changed when copying it across, especially as it was copying from Mac to Centos, so no line ending issues.

In conclusion: **use the file that `mongoexport` creates, not its contents!**