# Error during mongoimport

Tags: mongodb

I have a couple of valid JSON documents and I try to import them in mongodb.

```
{ "Books":
  [{ "ISBN":"ISBN-0-13-713526-2",
  "Price":85,
  "Edition":3,
  "Title":"A First Course in Database Systems",
  "Authors":[ {"First_Name":"Jeffrey", "Last_Name":"Ullman"},
              {"First_Name":"Jennifer", "Last_Name":"Widom"} ] }
,
{ "ISBN":"ISBN-0-13-815504-6",
  "Price":100,
  "Remark":"Buy this book bundled with 'A First Course' - a great deal!",
  "Title":"Database Systems:The Complete Book",
  "Authors":[ {"First_Name":"Hector", "Last_Name":"Garcia-Molina"},
              {"First_Name":"Jeffrey", "Last_Name":"Ullman"},
              {"First_Name":"Jennifer", "Last_Name":"Widom"} ] }],
"Magazines":
[{ "Title":"National Geographic",
  "Month":"January",
  "Year":2009 }
,
{ "Title":"Newsweek",
  "Month":"February",
  "Year":2009 },
{"Title": "Newsweek"}]
}
```

I got the following error:

> Sun Mar 24 15:23:27 exception:BSON representation of supplied JSON is
> too large: Failure parsing JSON string near: "Month":"J Sun Mar 24
>
> 15:23:27 exception:BSON representation of supplied JSON is too large:
> Failure parsing JSON string near: "Year":200 Sun Mar 24 15:28:23
>
> ERROR: encountered 28 errors

Could someone say what's wrong?

Comment: This is the entire JSON document you're trying to import? The error suggests that your file is [over 16MB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109474/mongodb-mongoimport-too-large-failure-parsing-errors).

Comment: This is the entire document, containing of 888 bytes

Answer (score 31, accepted):

By default `mongoimport` expects that each document will be on a single line of the JSON file. You need to pass `--jsonArray` to `mongoimport` using the format you're using, or just make sure that all of the data for a single document is on one line.

(I saved your file, as is, added the `--jsonArray`, option and it worked fine.)

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB has limit of 16 MB per document. If you want to overcome this limit you need to use `GridFS`. Plese look at documentation [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/gridfs/).

Comment: I posted the whole file, so it's 888 bytes in total

Comment: OK, now I see I thought you have a bunch of such entries.

Answer (score 1):

The following command from terminal worked good for me:

```
mongoimport -d my_db -c my_collection < my_json_file.json --batchSize 1
```

Some version needs to change the `--batchSize` 50 instead of 1 like below:

```
mongoimport -d my_db -c my_collection < my_json_file.json --batchSize 50
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import json file you can use this also

also for csv use `--type csv`

```
mongoimport --db database --collection collection_name filename.json --type json
```