# Importing JSON file using mongimport, keep getting `unexpected identifier`?

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I'm trying to add a JSON file to mongodb using `mongoimports` from terminal, here:

```
 mongoimport --db my_db --collection my_collection --file /content/2_read.json
```

I keep getting `JavaScript execution failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`
I ran my JSON through JSON Lint: http://jsonlint.com/   which says it's valid JSON.

I'm not sure what could be tripping up the import process?? Or how to investigate further to hunt down the issue?

**UPDATE**

1. Somebody suggested putting all on one-line. A decent suggestion. I tried it and it didn't work.
2. I tried importing a very very simple json file named `simple.json` with the content `{'content' : 'simple'}` But I'm still getting the same error using `mongoimport`. (I can add documents from `mongo` shell just fine.)

A sample of the JSON is below.

**2_read.json**

```
{
  "name" : "John",
  "tasks" : [
      {
       "ix" : "1",
       "description" : "description of task",
       "tags": []
      }, 
     {
      "ix": "2",
      "description" : "description of task",
      "tags" : []
     }
       ]
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error during mongoimport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15599716/error-during-mongoimport)

Comment: Maybe? But the person got a specific error, when the error I'm getting is generic (and less helpful). I also just tried adding --jsonArray but that didn't change anything. ;(

Comment: I did a complete newbie error. I thought you used `mongoimports` from the mongo shell prompt instead of the main terminal prompt. After that, I ran into the error of needing --jsonArray (and I got specific errors like in the post your pointed too) Thanks for highlighting that.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Answering my own question because **complete newbies** will appreciate the error and may run into it as they get started.

`mongoimport` is used from terminal, NOT within the `mongo` shell. Just like you don't use `npm` inside `node`. ;D

After figuring out my conceptual error there, I needed --jsonArray as pointed to by @WiredPrairie in the comments.

Comment: Even I did the same mistake. Thanks for sharing. It saved my time

Comment: Just made the same mistake. Thanks for answering your question.

Comment: Check the documents for erroneous text. I copied the json document from the web, and the browser through an error that was copied, when I copied the content of the page. Hopefully this helps you. JSLint helps too!

Comment: so what do you use inside mongo shell instead?

Answer (score 0):

The following command from terminal worked good for me:

```
mongoimport -d my_db -c my_collection < /content/2_read.json --batchSize 1
```

Comment: Hi. Im getting ERROR: unrecognised option '--batchSize' with the following command mongoimport --db ciudadDeBuenosAires --collection vehiculos-peajes < "/home/dantebarba/Descargas/ausapasovehiculo-2015.json" --batchSize 1