# Error in importing a csv file in mongoDB2.4

Tags: mongodb

I have installed mongoDB2.4 installed in my windows 7 os. I am new to mongoDB. I would like to import data from a csv file into the database. I have used the mongoimport command but it shows: 
Javascript execution failed: Syntax error: Unexpected identifier

my command in mongo shell was:

> mongoimport --db mentalhealth --collection bidyut --type csv --file \Users\Adrian\Desktop\Data_sorted.csv

PLEASE kindly provide an answer.

Comment: Mongoimport is a stand alone executable that needs to be run from the command prompt, not the shell.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500127/importing-json-file-using-mongimport-keep-getting-unexpected-identifier