# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier while importing JSON file in MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoimport

```
mongoimport --db test --collection collection1 --file c:/test.json
```

I got  SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier when executing the above command.

What is the problem of this script?

Thank you very much

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing JSON file using mongimport, keep getting \`unexpected identifier\`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500127/importing-json-file-using-mongimport-keep-getting-unexpected-identifier)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue when i tried to import json file from MongoDB Shell.
You can query it from command prompt.
My directory stucture:

```
C:\Program files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin\mongoimport.exe  
C:\filename.json
```

e.g.

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin> ./mongoimport --db dbname --collection collection_name C:\filename.json
```

Output should be:

```
2015-08-18T09:34:25.617-0700    connected to: localhost
2015-08-18T09:34:25.632-0700    imported 10 documents
```

Now switch back to MongoDB Shell:

```
 C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin> ./mongo
 use dbname
 db.collection_name.find().pretty()
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem here could be that you do not have your PATH set properly on your computer. If you are using Windows 10 -

- go to Control Panel and to System Security System
- then find the Advanced System Settings on the left panel.
- A window will pop up - at the bottom will be a button for Environment Variables
- Click that and the new window will have two panels of Variables
- find and select Path in both user / system panels - click edit and add a new path with the path to the MongoDb exe
- example : C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin