# Importing json documents into mongodb on mac

Tags: json, macos, mongodb, import, mongoimport

I am getting an error while importing a json document into mongoDB installed on my mac. I saw on another forum that the syntax is as follows:

```
mongoimport --db db1 --collection collection1 --file /Users/chummi/Desktop/zips.json
```

Here db1 is my database and collection1 is my collection and /Users/chummi/Desktop/zips.json is the path where the json document is present. When I run this command, am getting the following error

> "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

and not able to understand what this is.Please suggest if the syntax and the paths are correct?

Comment: can you provide the 1st row of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running mongoimport from inside the mongodb shell instead of the command line of your mac?  [Importing JSON file using mongimport, keep getting `unexpected identifier`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500127/importing-json-file-using-mongimport-keep-getting-unexpected-identifier)

Comment: Thank you very much, this has saved me a lot of time. The command is working now at the command line of my mac, initially I was running from inside the mongodb shell.