# How to import formatted json file to mongodb?

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoimport

I tried to import formatted json file into mongodb. but always it says that can't insert

```
{
  "marks": [
    {
      "class": {
        "className": "A"
      },
      "subject": "maths",
      "score": 43,
      "grade": "a"
    },
    {
      "class": {
        "className": "B"
      },
      "subject": "maths",
      "score": 34,
      "grade": "c"
    }
  ]
}
```

what is the reason for this. I used command `mongoimport --db sss --collection bbv --file a.json` and the error message is

```
exception:BSON representation of supplied JSON is too large: code FailedToParse: FailedToParse: Expecting '{': offset:0
```

Comment: It can't be formatted. Each document must be on only one line.

Answer (score 2):

try using

```
mongoimport -d DATABASE_NAME -c COLLECTION_NAME --file YOUR_JSON_FILE --jsonArray
```

as the import command instead.

@see: [Mongodb Mongoimport too large: Failure parsing errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109474/mongodb-mongoimport-too-large-failure-parsing-errors)

Comment: this was my issue. adding the `--jsonArray` flag at the end did the trick

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that this is not a valid JSON document.

If you have doubts like this, go to [JSON editor](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/) and paste it. It has an error on the line 9, and this means that you have to put `"a"` there. The same thing is with `grade c`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem e solve this change de locale.

Run this command for change locale
**dpkg-reconfigure locales**

Answer (score 0):

The json file is ok, but the problem is that to import it to MongoDB it should be in only one document by line. This was already commented by @WiredPrairie in this post:

The file **a.json**:

```
{"marks": [{"class": {"className": "A"}, "subject": "maths", "score": 43, "grade": "a"}, {"class": {"className": "B"}, "subject": "maths", "score": 34, "grade": "c"} ] }
```

Command **mongoimport**:

```
$ mongoimport --db sss --collection bbv --file a.json
```

[image]

And the result with **Robomongo**:

[image]